# How can I test whether a csv file is currently open and being written to - the file, not a file handle - with Perl?

Tags: perl

I've got a Clipper system writing csv files to a Windows directory.  I have a Perl script running on a Linux server that is reading a mount of that Windows directory and importing the files to a database.

Right now we're using flag files to indicate when a csv is no longer being written to; the flag file gets written after the csv is done.  I'd really rather just get what I need from the csv itself, but I can't seem to find a way to tell when the file is open and being written to.

`lsof` doesn't seem to answer my need.  I've tried using `flock` and open the file with an exclusive lock, thinking it might throw an error if the file is being modified, but it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You will find that all solutions to this are operating system specific. Using a separate file's existence is about as clean a solution as you'll find.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've decided.

Answer (score 0):

According to linux's man page for flock:

> flock()  does not lock files over NFS.
>   Use fcntl(2) instead: that does work
>   over NFS, given a sufficiently  recent
>   version  of  Linux  and  a server
>   which supports locking.

Have you tried using fcntl()?  Googling I find a few [examples](http://forum.soft32.com/linux/Samba-Smbd-Behaving-Weirdly-Exported-NFS-CIFS-Share-points-S-ftopict506047.html) of people using fcntl with CIFS.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work since you're mounting to Windows, but maybe [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) would help.

Answer (score 0):

If inotify does not work, use Poor Man's Polling: if modification time is older than two seconds, the file is finished writing.

Comment: It takes too much time.  We might feed through 10 thousand+ files in a day.  2 seconds for each add a lot of time to the processing.  I tested 690 files and it took about 25 minutes to import them.  Using the flag files, it only took about 50 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux%3a%3aInotify2) or [File::Monitor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aMonitor) would do the trick for monitoring the files.